# Laravel filesystem outside project

Tags: php, laravel

Can I use laravel filesystem to save file outside current project? 
I have this structure: project and cdn.

I've tried custom driver but fails. It wont put any file at cdn folder.

```
'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => '~/Code/cdn.web/storage',
    ],

$store  = Storage::disk('custom')->put('index.txt', 'contents');
```

I've followed this answer too [Storing files outside the Laravel 5 Root Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576689/storing-files-outside-the-laravel-5-root-folder)
But there is no custom driver.

Is there anyway to make it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer.

Laravel doesn't support `~` on the path.

I need to put full path to make it working.

```
'custom' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => '/home/vagrant/Code/cdn.web/storage',
],
```